# Whose signature is shown in the Spectre teaser?

Tags: james-bond, spectre

I was watching the [teaser trailer for *Spectre*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kQx_SrKS1sQ), and approximately 28 seconds in, we see this signature:

[image]

The surname of the signatory looks like “Bond”, but it’s certainly not James, nor does it seem to be the name of either of his parents (Andrew and Monique). I think it looks a bit like “Chairman”, but that seems like a strange name.

Since this field is labelled “Legal Guardian(s)”, and given the surname, I’m assuming this is a member of Bond’s family. But I don’t recall anybody in any of the Bond films with a remotely similar name. It is, of course, possible that this is an entirely new character.

**Whose signature is this?**

---

I’ve included the full screencap below, but the rest of the image may be spoilery:

> [image]

Comment: Spoilers are fine here, as long as they're not in the question... also, is it really a spoiler if it's in the trailer?

Comment: @Catija I tend to err on the side of caution with these things. Feel free to edit to un-spoil if you feel strongly.

Comment: I don't feel strongly about spoilers.  They're neither required nor banned, I was just pointing it out. :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Charmian Bond**, James's aunt and legal guardian. She was mentioned in his obituary in Fleming's novel *You only Live Twice*. From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Bond_%28literary_character%29):

> After the death of his parents, Bond goes to live with his aunt, Miss Charmian Bond, in the village of Pett Bottom, where he completes his early education.

Charmian was [the name of Fleming's cousin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_Only_Live_Twice_%28novel%29#Background) who married his brother Richard. It's often misspelled as Charmain and Charmaine.

Comment: Ah, so my guess of Chairman was actually quite close. Thanks!